# proof that a tangent map is surjective

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If I have an equivariant morphism $F:X\rightarrow Y$ and I want to prove that if the tangent map is onto over every point of $X$.  Where $X$ and $Y$ are affine varieties  invariants by the action of $GL_3$. I know the subset $A=\{x\in X ;\ \ \mbox{the tangent map is not onto on } x \}$ is closed.

Supposing that $A$ is not empty; **if $A$ was invariant** then it contents a closed orbit, by the other side I know that the tangent map is onto on a representative of that closed orbit (in this particular case), and I would have a contradiction. Then I have that $A=\emptyset$ .
How can I prove that $A$ is invariant?

Comment: Use the fact that $F$ is equivariant to claim that if $dF_x : T_xX \rightarrow T_{f(x)}Y$ is not surjective then the same holds for $dF_{gx} : T_{gx}X \rightarrow T_{gF(x)}Y = T_{F(g(x))}Y$. This proves that $A$ is invariant under the group $G$.